# Overstayed my UK visa 10 years ago, how do I reapply for a new one?

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, overstaying

I have a problem. I overstayed my UK visitor visa for about 9 months and returned voluntarily in June 2008. I was 16, and no paperwork or administrative proceedings occurred. I did not get any deported stamp on my passport.
Prior to my exit I had been a frequent visitor since 2005 and never overstayed.

I got back to my country and had to apply for the new electronic passport because we were no longer using the old one.

However, I decided to use my real age which is 1992 compared to 1994 that was on my old passport.

The passport number on my old passport is different from the new passport I got too.

I have traveled to India and the U.S with the new passport and the visa is still valid until 2020.

However, since I left the UK in 2008 I never applied for visa or made any attempt in visiting.

I plan to go there for holiday this year and want to apply. How do I go about it? If I am asked if I have visited before or overstayed on the form do I indicate yes or no? What are my chances of getting it, and how do I got about the age difference?

Comment: Apply just like everyone and tell the truth. Your chance of getting the visa is slim. I would estimate your chances of refusal around 25%. See https://ukvisa.blog/2018/11/23/uk-visa-success-rate/ . You were a minor when you left, that will be considered in your favor.

Comment: @Lizzy The application does ask about previous visits and overstays (not just to the UK) and so you will have to declare your travel history. Attempting to hide it will get you a ban. As regards the age difference, you’ll have to disclose the explanation for it and hipe for the best. Holding a current US visa may help your credibility.

Comment: @Traveller the application does not explicitly ask about an overstay. The UK had no exit checks in 2008 (even electronic ones like they have since 2014) and the application only asks about visits to the UK in the last 10 years. I would be more concerned about the fake date of birth. Would a fake date of birth render the old passport false?

Comment: @greatone: she is not to blame about wrong date on old passport (she was minor, and the birth date, name, etc. should be checked by authorities). To me seems like a common error on issuing passport (and one ask passport when one has travel plan, so a replacement is often not done).

Comment: Ok. But with respect to the date. I did an affidavit before I could even change the date on the new electronic passport.

Comment: @greatone You’re right, the OP would only have to include visits in the last 10 years. There is however a question asking if the applicant has ever been required to leave the UK - it’s not clear from the OP’s question what the circumstances were regarding ‘returning voluntarily’ and whether she would have to answer Yes.

Comment: @Traveller required to leave here means told to go. Unless he was officially given a IS151A or similar he can answer no.

Comment: What’s an IS151A ?? I wasn’t given anything.

Comment: @Lizzy It would help get better answers if you explained whether you just left of your own free will (and UK Border agents didn’t pick up on your overstay in any way - including a verbal conversation), or whether any kind of administrative removal proceedings were taken by U.K. Immigration Enforcement (leading to your voluntary departure at your own expense). https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/606970/GI-Re-entry-bans-v7.pdf#page1

Comment: @Traveller I left on my own free will. I was 16 then, there was no  form of file filling or administrative proceedings. At the airport. This happened 2008.

Answer (score 2):

There are details to be aware of, but basically you apply as anybody.

Fill out the application including the fact that you have overstayed and that your passport details back then were not the actual truth.
Both those details will count against you but you were a minor at the time and that will make them count less.
Do not assume that a new passport makes them not matching you with your previous passport. If found lying about it, you will get a long term ban and may never be trusted again to get visa, not just by the UK but also by other countries they work with.

If getting a visa for the UK is very important for you, you may want to get a good lawyer in the UK to help you with the application, so you do not ruin your chances with mistakes or by leaving out things you should have added.

You can be sure your application will be checked very carefully, but as you were a minor you do stand a good chance of getting a visa, under normal, non COVID 19 conditions. (Do not try to get a visa for a casual visit till the situation has gone back to normal after COVID 19.)